# Breeze and Internet explorer 8 issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, breeze, single-page-application

I have  just started learning SPA apps and I am having issues running it on IE8. I am using mvc4 and EF. The app is built using durandal.

I am using jquery 1.10 because jquery 2 does not work on IE 8.

Basically the error im getting is

```
'Unhandled exception at line 786, column 9 in http://localserver/scripts/breeze.debug.js

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method'.
```

The app runs fine on firefox and chrome.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest Breeze. v 1.3.6?

Comment: Yes I did. I the script that is breaking is breeze.debug.js. The method is
    function exec(self)- the line is return contexts.some(function(context){return context.fn(context,self.v);});

Comment: @JayTraband - Yes I did. I the script that is breaking is breeze.debug.js. The method is function exec(self)- the line is return contexts.some(function(context){return context.fn(context,self.v);});

Comment: @CodeNoob, could you send your test solution reproducing the problem to breeze@ideablade.com. This way we can further investigate.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have included  [es5-shim.js and es5-sham.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) before 'breeze.js'.

For example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="Scripts/es5-shim.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/es5-sham.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/q.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
```

It is documented in the [prerequisites](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/prerequisites) section, but none of the samples use it. It would be nice if the samples where updated to include these. I know I struggled to find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers miss some of the array functions, so add some javascript :)

```
    if (!('bind' in Function.prototype)) {
        Function.prototype.bind= function(owner) {
            var that= this;
            if (arguments.length<=1) {
                return function() {
                    return that.apply(owner, arguments);
                };
            } else {
                var args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                return function() {
                    return that.apply(owner, arguments.length===0? args : args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
                };
            }
        };
    }

    if (!('trim' in String.prototype)) {
        String.prototype.trim= function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
        };
    }

    if (!('indexOf' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.indexOf= function(find, i /*opt*/) {
            if (i===undefined) i= 0;
            if (i<0) i+= this.length;
            if (i<0) i= 0;
            for (var n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        };
    }
    if (!('lastIndexOf' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.lastIndexOf= function(find, i /*opt*/) {
            if (i===undefined) i= this.length-1;
            if (i<0) i+= this.length;
            if (i>this.length-1) i= this.length-1;
            for (i++; i-->0;) /* i++ because from-argument is sadly inclusive */
                if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        };
    }
    if (!('forEach' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.forEach= function(action, that /*opt*/) {
            for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this)
                    action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
        };
    }
    if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
            var other= new Array(this.length);
            for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this)
                    other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
            return other;
        };
    }
    if (!('filter' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.filter= function(filter, that /*opt*/) {
            var other= [], v;
            for (var i=0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this && filter.call(that, v= this[i], i, this))
                    other.push(v);
            return other;
        };
    }
    if (!('every' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.every= function(tester, that /*opt*/) {
            for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this && !tester.call(that, this[i], i, this))
                    return false;
            return true;
        };
    }
    if (!('some' in Array.prototype)) {
        Array.prototype.some= function(tester, that /*opt*/) {
            for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
                if (i in this && tester.call(that, this[i], i, this))
                    return true;
            return false;
        };
    }
```